# Get Count Based on Combinations of Values from Second Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table format like below:

```
Id Code
1   A
1   B
2   A
3   A
3   C
4   A
4   B
```

I am trying to get count of code combinations like below:

```
Code Count
A,B     2  -- Row 1,2 and Row 6,7 
A       1  -- Row 3
A,C     1  -- Row 4
```

I am unable to get the combination result. All I can do is group by but I am not getting count of IDs based in combinations.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: it is MS SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate the rows, somehow, and do that twice.  The code looks something like this:

```
select codes, count(*) as num_ids
from (select id, group_concat(code order by code) as codes
      from t
      group by id
     ) id
group by code;
```

`group_concat()` might be spelled `listagg()` or `string_agg()` depending on the database.

In SQL Server, use `string_agg()`:

```
select codes, count(*) as num_ids
from (select id, string_agg(code, ',') within group (order by code) as codes
      from t
      group by id
     ) id
group by code;
```